# How can I add features to my mapbox-gl map in angular through a forEach loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox-gl

Because I need more than a single line on my map I'm trying to put multiple features in a single source.

Currently my `typescript` code looks like this where `myRoutes` is the array containing all the routes (coordinates for the line to draw), however this isn't the correct way to do it and it doesn't work (only the first line gets drawn).

```
myRoutes.forEach((element: any) => {
    this.map.addSource("route", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [
                {
                    type: "Feature",
                    properties: {},
                    geometry: {
                        type: "LineString",
                        coordinates: [
                            [element.fromLon, element.fromLat],
                            [element.toLon, element.toLat]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    });
});

this.map.addLayer({ ... });
```

Looking at the official documentation of MapBox ([link](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/)) it's possible to add more than one in the following way:

```
...
{
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-121.415061, 40.506229]
    }
},
{
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-121.505184, 40.488084]
    }
},
...
```

So my question is how could I generate these blocks automatically with a forEach in my `typescript` file using the data of `myRoutes`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection of features but only add it once as source for example:

```
const features =  myRoutes.map((element: any) => {
            {
                type: "Feature",
                properties: {},
                geometry: {
                    type: "LineString",
                    coordinates: [
                        [element.fromLon, element.fromLat],
                        [element.toLon, element.toLat]
                    ]
                }
         });

this.map.addSource("route", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features
    },
});
```